# Nonexistent route breaks the site

Tags: 8

I'm new to Drupal and have been using a few modules to build a site. I've installed link icon and have used it to make a block type and a block which I have then deleted. Then an error like this showed up:
`Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "linkicon.settings" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 208 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php).`

````
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getPathFromRoute('linkicon.settings', Array) (Line: 68)
Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->getPathFromRoute('linkicon.settings', Array) (Line: 791)
Drupal\Core\Url->getInternalPath() (Line: 135)
Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator->generate('Linkicon', Object) (Line: 95)
Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Link::preRenderLink(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. Support for this callback implementation is deprecated in 8.8.0 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'silenced_deprecation', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 501)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 117)
__TwigTemplate_a4627177b33000f8b0aa8b107c9f0ef6178614c89b6a7100401a3236a6320938->getmenu_links(Array, Object, 1) (Line: 124)
__TwigTemplate_a4627177b33000f8b0aa8b107c9f0ef6178614c89b6a7100401a3236a6320938->getmenu_links(Array, Object, 0) (Line: 60)
__TwigTemplate_a4627177b33000f8b0aa8b107c9f0ef6178614c89b6a7100401a3236a6320938->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 455)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 422)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 434)
Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template('core/themes/stable/templates/navigation/menu--toolbar.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('menu__toolbar', Array) (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 156)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 157)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain(Array) (Line: 115)
Drupal\toolbar\Controller\ToolbarController::preRenderGetRenderedSubtrees(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. Support for this callback implementation is deprecated in 8.8.0 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'silenced_deprecation', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 156)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 157)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain(Array) (Line: 299)
toolbar_get_rendered_subtrees() (Line: 324)
_toolbar_get_subtrees_hash() (Line: 167)
toolbar_toolbar()
call_user_func_array('toolbar_toolbar', Array) (Line: 403)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('toolbar') (Line: 81)
Drupal\toolbar\Element\Toolbar::preRenderToolbar(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. Support for this callback implementation is deprecated in 8.8.0 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'silenced_deprecation', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 501)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 96)
__TwigTemplate_36b55b2cdf160af87a66085795ed11cacb844fa1a6a61aab58232c38ca9b0c0e->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 455)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 422)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 434)
Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template('themes/contrib/news_zymphonies_theme/templates/layout/html.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 147)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 148)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 694)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The route exists in the module code:

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/linkicon/-/blob/8.x-1.x/linkicon.routing.yml

Check to make sure you have that file on your system. Clear your registry. If that doesn't work, then you should reinstall the module.

Comment: what do u mean by clear registry?

Comment: Admin -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance.